# Looping through Core Data relationship

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

In my calendarViewController I'd like to prepare an array containing dates. In my model i have to-may relationship where one medicine can have multiple dates of taking pill. How can i perform a loop through this set to append an array ?
My models:

```
extension Medicine {

@NSManaged var amount: String?
@NSManaged var endDate: String?
@NSManaged var name: String?
@NSManaged var time: String?
@NSManaged var notificationSet: NSNumber?
@NSManaged var taken: NSOrderedSet?

}
```

Model Dates

```
extension Dates {

@NSManaged var date: NSDate?
@NSManaged var takes: Medicine?
```

}

I'd like to perform loop like this ,but instead these dates i'd like those from CoreData:

```
var dates = [NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*2), NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*3), NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*5), NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60*60*24*7)]

func calendar(calendar: CKCalendarView!, configureDateItem dateItem: CKDateItem!, forDate date: NSDate!) {


    for dateTaken in dates {
        if calendar.date(date, isSameDayAsDate: dateTaken) {
            dateItem.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Please go through below link :  http://www.raywenderlich.com/14742/core-data-on-ios-5-tutorial-how-to-work-with-relations-and-predicates     it would be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

Fetch your `Medicine` entity and then create the array like this:

```
let dates = medicine.taken.map { $0.date }
```

Not sure about the `NSOrderedSet` which tends to be buggy so I generally avoid it, but you can try appending `as! [NSDate]` to make sure you have an proper array of dates.